# How to get the next element which has the attribute tabindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the tabindex value of next element to be assigned to its previous element, When I tried running this code getting undefined for the variable el.

```
if(event.keyCode == 9){
    $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
    var el = $(this).closest('input, select').attr('tabindex');
    var tV = el.val();
    if(el != ' ' || el != null){
        $(this).attr('tabindex', tV - 1);
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

Comment: provide us your html pls

Comment: $(this) refers to the jqueryui datepicker element..

Comment: if you want the next element, just do `var el = $(this).next().attr('tabindex');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are picking the next input/select element and getting its tabindex. If there is no tabindex defined, you get the `undefined`.

Try this:

```
$(this).nextAll("[tabindex]:first").attr('tabindex');
```

Answer (score 4):

Well it's pretty basic selector logic with the `document.querySelector()` API. Let's say we have the `mainElement` and we would like to get the next element under `mainElement` with a `tabindex = -1` attribute and value.

Lets see;

```js
var   mainElement = document.querySelector('#main'),
inputWithTabIndex = mainElement.querySelector('[tabindex = "-1"]');
console.log(inputWithTabIndex);
setTimeout(function() {
             inputWithTabIndex.setAttribute("tabindex","0");
             console.log(inputWithTabIndex);
           },1000);
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type here">
  </div>
  <div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type here">
  </div>
  <div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type here" tabindex = "-1">
  </div>
  <div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type here">
  </div>
</div>
```